# Missing right paranthesis

Tags: oracle

```
create table testk
(
    UserID Number,
    Active number(1,0)
 )

Insert into testk
Values (UID,Iff(active== 'True','1','0'))
with names as (1,'true')
```

Error Message : missing right paranthesis

Comment: There is no `IFF` in SQL or Oracle

Comment: `IFF` aside, aren't you aware that you open 3 parenthesis but close 2?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Insert one row `(1, 'true')` into the table? Or insert multiple rows from another table into the new one? Where does `active` come from? Your insert statement is invalid and looks incomplete to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's invalid, as far as Oracle is concerned. `CASE` might help, though.

```
SQL> create table testk ( UserID Number, Active number(1,0) );

Table created.

SQL> insert into testk values (uid, case when '&active' = 'true' then 1 else 0 end);
Enter value for active: true
old   1: insert into testk values (uid, case when '&active' = 'true' then 1 else 0 end)
new   1: insert into testk values (uid, case when 'true' = 'true' then 1 else 0 end)

1 row created.

SQL> select * From testk;

    USERID     ACTIVE
---------- ----------
       165          1

SQL>
```

Actual `INSERT` statement might differ from posted above, depending on tool you use (this is SQL*Plus) and what `active` represents).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have semi-colon after your CREATE TABLE statement:

```
create table testk
  (
  UserID Number,
  Active number(1,0)
  );
/* ^-add this */
```

Further, your INSERT statement is not valid in Oracle. Perhaps you meant:

```
Insert into testk (UserID, Active)
Values (UID, CASE WHEN &active = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```